# Принудительная проксификация приложения

Tags: c#

Интересует возможность принудительной проксификации приложения. Само не умеет, а декомпилировать и лезть в исходный код мало того, что незаконно, да не особо и знаний хватает. Желательно на C#. Как можно реализовать? Может подскажете хотя бы в какую стороны рыть, какие библиотеки есть, API или в какой области именно это искать?

И еще дополнительно два вопроса. В работе планируется менять прокси динамически, но есть возможность прослушивать трафик приложения через один прокси. Что будет легче, прослушивать один порт(например 127.0.0.1:9000), как это делает Fiddler или перехватывать напрямую?
И как лучше реализовать динамическую смену по сигналу, знаю есть возможность создать сервер и клиент на сокетах и через телнет менять. Или же есть более простой метод?

Answer (score 3):

Вам поможет [Freecap](http://www.freecap.ru/). Также там доступен исходный код.

Comment: Freecap, Widecap, Proxyfier и т.д. проксификаторы не поддерживают смену прокси в середине работы. То есть мне по сигналу нужно сменить прокси. Ну или хотя бы при запуске задать нужный прокси через командную строку. Я не нашел ни одного готового решения, кроме Tor, где реализованы оба варианта. Но в Tor нельзя динамически менять свои прокси.

Comment: ну так посмотрите исходники, там точно есть процедура включения/выключения, значит можно дописать и условие. Delphi не такой сложный язык.

Comment: через "командноую строку" не помню, но конфигу ему подсунуть точно можно при запуске. А готовить её динамически - это просто.

Comment: VB может и не сложный, но я его почему-то не перевариваю никак. Эти конструкции start end вместо лаконичных {} меня как-то сбивают с толку. :) Поэтому и не учил его.
Но спасибо за совет.
Я пробовал менять запись реестра для widecap, но у меня не вышло, меняло обратно значение. Видел там можно хранить, вроде, в ini. Конечно каждый раз перезапускать несподручно, но все же какой-никакой выход. :)